# Snap vertices to nearest face along normals

Tags: vertices, snapping

Do I have to use the shrinkwrap modifier to achieve this? I have two objects, an ornament which goes on a basin. There is only a very narrow gap between them, but visible if you zoom close enough. I would like to make one object out of both, without gaps in between them.

Edit: Added picture and description.

[image]
As seen in the picture, the gaps are encircled red. The basin goes down to the violet line where the ornament overlaps it.

Comment: Hello :). Please, add some images to better illustrate the question.

Comment: yes, snap with Shrinkwrap, or join the two meshes?

Comment: Added a picture. I doubt that a shrinkwrap modifier is possible, since the basin goes not down. It will destroy the ornament, since it is only possible to shrinkwrap whole objects onto whole  objects?